# How to execute a method the first time and on each retry?

Tags: c#, polly, retry-logic

I'm using `Polly` for a retry policy:

```
var policy = Policy
    .Handle<DatabaseException>(x => x.DatabaseErrors.ContainsKey(2601))
    .WaitAndRetry(new[]
    {
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500),
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000),
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500)
    }, (exception, timeSpan) => {
        FirstAndRetryMethod();
    });

policy = Policy.Excecute(() => DoSomething());
```

With the above, `FirstAndRetryMethod` is called as expected on `Retry`. How can I call this also the first time `DoSomething` is executed?

Comment: `FirstAndRetryMethod` is called whenever the `DoSomething` throws a `DatabaseException` with error code 2601 and you have not exhausted the retry count. Can `FirstAndRetryMethod` throw the same exception with the same status code?

Comment: @PeterCsala No.

Comment: Does it produce any side-effect? Is the ordering of the method calls (`FirstAndRetryMethod` + `DoSomething` vs `DoSomething` + `FirstAndRetryMethod`) important?

Comment: @PeterCsala Yes order is important.

Comment: The `onRetry` delegate is executed when the policy is sure that it will be triggered (the thrown exception is handled and the retry count is not exceeded) but before the wait duration (a.k.a penalty). So it is called after the initial (failed) call as well.

Comment: @PeterCsala And how can I call the method before the initial call?

Comment: You said that ordering matters, so why do want to call that before the initial call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236687/discussion-between-peter-csala-and-ivan-mark-debono).

Comment: Ordering matters. `FirstAndRetryMethod` must always be called before. On initial call of `DoSomething` or on retries.

Comment: Then it is quite simple :D `policy.Excecute(() => { FirstAndRetryMethod(); DoSomething(); });` and forgot the `onRetry` delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Retry policy defines an [onRetry](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#onretry--onretryasync) optional delegate which is called after the failed attempt but before the wait duration (so called penalty).

So, lets suppose you have the following implementations for `FirstAndRetryMethod` and `DoSomething` for debugging purposes:

```
static int onretryCallCount = 0;
static void FirstAndRetryMethod() {
    Console.WriteLine("FirstAndRetryMethod has been called for the " + onretryCallCount++ + "th time");
}

static int doSomethingCallCount = 0;
static void DoSomething() {
    Console.WriteLine("DoSomething has been called for the " + doSomethingCallCount++ + "th time");
    throw new DatabaseException { ... };
}
```

Then the output will look like this:

```
DoSomething has been called for the 0th time
FirstAndRetryMethod has been called for the 0th time
DoSomething has been called for the 1th time
FirstAndRetryMethod has been called for the 1th time
DoSomething has been called for the 2th time
FirstAndRetryMethod has been called for the 2th time
DoSomething has been called for the 3th time
```

Because you have defined 3 timestamps that's why your retry count is 3.

- You have an initial attempt and 3 retries (4 in total) (`DoSomething has been called for the ...`)
- and 3 onRetry calls (`FirstAndRetryMethod has been called for the ...`).

---

If you want to make sure that `FirstAndRetryMethod` is called prior each and every attempt (including the initial) then you should call it inside the `Execute` delegate:

```
policy.Execute(() => { FirstAndRetryMethod(); DoSomething(); });
```

and you should delete the `onRetry` part of your policy definition.

Then the output will look like this:

```
FirstAndRetryMethod has been called for the 0th time
DoSomething has been called for the 0th time
FirstAndRetryMethod has been called for the 1th time
DoSomething has been called for the 1th times
FirstAndRetryMethod has been called for the 2th time
DoSomething has been called for the 2th time
FirstAndRetryMethod has been called for the 3th time
DoSomething has been called for the 3th time
```

Now you have 4 `FirstAndRetryMethod` and 4 `DoSomething` calls.